# Derivative of a function with quotient rule: $\frac {3x^{3}} {2(x^{2}-4)}.$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The function is: $$\dfrac {3x^{3}} {2(x^{2}-4)}.$$

I'm using quotient rule:
$$\dfrac{g(x)\cdot f'(x) - g'(x)\cdot f(x)}{{2(x^{2}-4)}^{2}}$$

The result i have is: $$\dfrac {3x^{2}} {2(x-2)(x+2)}$$

Comment: i changed,i did a mistake while writing text command form

Comment: The bottom isn't squared as stated in the rule.

Comment: Write your steps and we could help to find your mistake.

Comment: Note you should have $[2(x^2-4)^2]^2$ in the denominator. The $2$ also gets squared.

Answer (score 1):

$$h(x) = \dfrac{3x^{3}}{2(x^{2}-4)}$$

$$h'(x) = \dfrac{18x^2(x^2 - 4) - 12x(x^3)}{4(x^2-4)^2}$$

$$ = \dfrac{18x^4 - 72x^2 - 12x^4}{\underbrace{4(x^2 - 4)^2}_{ = (2(x^2 - 4))^2}}$$

$$ = \frac {6x^4 -72x^2}{4(x^2-4)}= \frac {3x^4 - 36x^2}{2(x^2 - 4)^2}$$

$$ = \frac{3x^2(x^2 - 12)}{2(x^2 - 4)^2}$$